# Get google adwords statistics from python (blockspring)

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I want to generate reports from multiple ad accounts.
Firstly google adwords.

Applying for a google adwords api token looks rather cumbersome.
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start

So I'm using https://www.blockspring.com/ which has among other things facebook ads integration which might justify the price in the future.

```
import blockspring
import json

res = blockspring.runParsed("performance-report-adwords", {
    "customer_id": CUSTOMER_ID,
    "report_type": "Account Performance Report",
    "start_date": "2016/01/01",
    "end_date": "2016/01/08",
    "metrics": "Clicks",
    "filters": None,
    "include_zero_impressions": True},
    {"api_key": API_KEY})
print res.getErrors()
```

My program above produces this output:

```
[{u'message': [[u'/tmp/blockspring/cd161b01894db9e9fac4b852752bfd8a/cd161b01894db9e9fac4b852752bfd8a.py', 145, u'block', u'skip_report_summary=True, include_zero_impressions=include_zero
_impressions)'], [u'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleads/adwords.py', 647, u'DownloadReportAsStringWithAwql', u'self._SerializeAwql(query, file_format), kwargs)'], [u'/usr/lo
cal/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleads/adwords.py', 778, u'_DownloadReportAsStream', u'raise self._ExtractError(e)']], u'title': u'Google Adwords Error - Type: QueryError.PARSING_FAIL
ED\nTrigger: None\nField Path: None'}]
```

So it looks like the query is wrong.
I've tried a string and an array for the metrics parameter but get the same error.

What is the correct way to query blockspring?

Comment: Trying making dates in this format "2016-01-08" and enter metrics as an array -  ["Clicks"]. Does that work?

Comment: @bumpkin, the format the OP os using is  is exactly the same as the the docs example

Comment: @bumpkin, unfortunately not. Exact same error. I tried ["Clicks"] and your date format first.